# Why does GitHub prompt me for password authentication (which fails) in one project, while the fancy new way still works for other projects?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have created an SSH key for GitHub, and until now worked to push my changes in all projects.
(That includes new projects, which I created after the SSH key.)
I just type `git push -u origin main`.

Now I deleted a project locally, and pulled it from GitHub. I assumed the result would be the same.
But when I want to push my changes, suddenly GitHub asks me for username and password.
And when I enter them, it of course tells me, that this does not work anymore.

```
tilman@t570:~/learn_py/discrete_research$ git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': entenschule
Password for 'https://entenschule@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/entenschule/discrete_research.git/'
```

How can I tell GitHub to please do for this project, what it still does for all the others?

Comment: Compare the output of `git remote show origin` between the two of them. I suspect the failed project is cloned through HTTPS, while the successful one use SSH

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is in the comment by @Martheen.

The project was indeed pulled with the HTTPS URL:
`git clone https://github.com/entenschule/discrete_research.git`

I cloned it again with SSH:
`git clone git@github.com:entenschule/discrete_research.git`

Now it works.